# Write Long JSON document with Python

Tags: python, json

I need to write a json document to a file. It's an AWS policy and is a little long, so I'm having trouble with the formatting.

This is my function that I'm having a problem with:

```
def create_iam_policy(user_name):
    # Set the date
    today = datetime.today()
    today = today.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    # Set the output file
    output_dir = "../../../json/iam"
    output_file = output_dir + 'pol-aws-secrets-manager-' + user_name + today +'.json'
    create_work_dir(output_dir)

    policy_doc = "{
    \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",
    \"Statement\": [
        {
            \"Effect\": \"Allow\",
            \"Action\": [
                \"secretsmanager:ListSecrets\",
                \"secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword\"
            ],
            \"Resource\": \"*\"
        },
        {
            \"Effect\": \"Allow\",
            \"Action\": [
                \"kms:Decrypt\"
            ],
            \"Resource\": \"arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:832839043616:key/24260438-1817-4e0b-897c-7f7958edba98\"
        },
        {
            \"Effect\": \"Allow\",
            \"Action\": [
                \"kms:List*\"
            ],
            \"Resource\": \"*\"
        },
        {
            \"Effect\": \"Allow\",
            \"Action\": [
                \"secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy\",
                \"secretsmanager:GetSecretValue\",
                \"secretsmanager:DescribeSecret\",
                \"secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds\"
            ],
            \"Resource\": \"*\",
            \"Condition\": {
                \"ForAnyValue:StringEquals\": {
                    \"secretsmanager:ResourceTag/Name\": user_name
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}"
```

This is the original json document that I am working with: [AWS Policy document](https://pastebin.com/jHfjSiLj)

When I run the above code I get this error:

```
 File ".\aws_iam_rotate_keys.py", line 261
    policy_doc = "{
                  ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

How can I format this long json document correctly so that it doesn't throw an error?

Comment: Don't do this. That's JSON; write a Python dict, then serialize it using `json.dumps()`.

Comment: But even if you did for some reason need to write it as a string, you should use the triple-quotes to surround the whole thing, then there's no need to escape each quote.

Comment: Ok, sounds good. I will try that. My only goal is to write this to a file. I'll see how it goes. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dict, populate it and use json dump in order to save it to file.

See [here](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/) for more.

```
import json

policy_doc = {'x':7}
with open('out.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(policy_doc,f)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to convert this document into a dict. The json document has a couple different levels. I'm not sure how to represent that in a dictionary. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Sure. `policy_doc = {'x':7,'sub_policy':{'y':12,'z':{'key':'val'}}}`

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. I will give that a go!

Comment: That works great! Thank you!

Ok thanks! That works GREAT to get past that formatting error. I now have a better idea how to do this!

However when I go to write the file, there's nothing there. I think I'm doing something else wrong.This is my code:
`today = datetime.today()
output_dir = "../../../json/iam"

output_file = output_dir + 'pol-aws-secrets-manager-' + user_name + today +'.json'policy_doc = {"blah:"blah"}

with open(output_file, 'w+') as writer:

json.dump(policy_doc,writer)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please explain what is wrong  when you try to save the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a string literal, for example you're getting the JSON from somewhere else and don't want to go to the trouble of converting it to a Python object only to convert it back to JSON, use triple-quotes so you can include line breaks.

If there are any backslashes in it, you can also put an `r` at the beginning to avoid having to double-escape everything. Not necessary in this case.

```
policy_doc = """{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:ListSecrets",
                "secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:832839043616:key/24260438-1817-4e0b-897c-7f7958edba98"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
                "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "secretsmanager:ResourceTag/Name": user_name
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}"""
```

Another alternative is to put the JSON in its own file and have your Python script read it. This makes it easier to edit the JSON file if necessary, since you don't have to worry about the syntax of two different languages.

Comment: That's a very good idea! I considered putting this document into a file and reading it from there into the python script. However, I need to programmatically alter the user name. So I think I need to keep the doc in the program so that I can alter the user name.

Comment: You can put a placeholder of some sort in the JSON file and alter that after reading it. For example, put `$username` where you want the username to go, and after reading the file, do `policy_doc = policy_doc.replace("$username", username)`. (Ordinarily you'd want to use regular Python string formatting, in which case you would use `%s` or `{}` as your placeholder, but that can be confusing mixed with code in some other language.)